# How to install a package from external source in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I got an error when doing `apt-get update`:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 perl : Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1) but 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So manually I have downloaded `perl_5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1.debian.tar.gz` from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1. When I extract the `tar.gz` file, it gives a debian folder with some files.

Now how could I eliminate that error?

Output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-sublime-text-3,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Sublime Text 3 Installer,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-sublime-text-3,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Sublime Text 3 Installer,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 7 / 8 / 9 Installer PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 7 / 8 / 9 Installer PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45167/discussion-on-question-by-kiran-raju-how-to-install-a-package-from-external-sour).

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure about this, but it looks like you have broken dependencies. 
Open the Terminal from the Menu and start with the commands:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install gtkorphan
```

The && is used to run the second command if the first command runs successfully.

Continue by running:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

This is used to double-check that you have all the updates.

To clear out the broken packages use the command:

```
sudo aptitude -f
```

It brings up a beautiful interface to search, navigate, install, update and otherwise to manage packages.

please note that **it is bad practice to use aptitude and apt-get interchangeably, as they record separately the changes made by a user**

Recommended reading [apt-get vs aptitude](https://pthree.org/2007/08/12/aptitude-vs-apt-get/)

Comment: aptitude is not installed in my system.. now i can't able to install anything in my machine due to this issue so finally it won't work out.